# Proving $A \to \exists x B \Rightarrow \exists x (A\to B)$ if $x$ is not free in $A$

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Assume $A,B$ are first order formulas, with $x$ not free in $A$. I'd like to prove (in the two-sided sequent calculus for classical logic) that
$$
A\to \exists x B \Rightarrow \exists x (A\to B)
$$

By left introduction, it would suffice to find some $C$ such that the sequents

$$A\to \exists x B\Rightarrow C$$
and
$$ A\to \exists x B,C\Rightarrow\exists x (A\to B)$$
are both derivable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a derivation (I hope you'll excuse my switching to $\vdash$, which is how I learned ;)

[image]

---

Hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a nonconstructive statement.  Specifically, $A \to \exists x .Bx$ is saying that, given all of the constructions of $A$, you are able to convert those into the construction of $x$.  On the other hand $\exists x.A \to Bx$ is saying that you are able to construct an $x$ out of nothing.  This is stronger than the first claim (at least in this case).

So you need to assume that $x$ can always be constructed, that is, that $\exists x.Bx \lor \lnot \exists x.Bx$, so try instead to prove both

$$\begin{array} {rccl}
\exists x . Bx,& A \to \exists x . Bx &\vdash& \exists x . A \to Bx \\
\lnot \exists x . Bx,& A \to \exists x . Bx &\vdash& \exists x . A \to Bx
\end{array}$$

then stitch those together.